# Next.js server stops a few seconds after running "npm run dev"

Tags: npm, next.js, yarnpkg

After creating **Next.js** app using `npx create-next-app` and running `npm run dev` after the installation completed, in the terminal it shows the following:

> ready - started server on `0.0.0.0:3000`, url: `http://localhost:3000`

And then after a few seconds it stops and there are no errors. My node.js version is `v18.15.0` and my **NPM version** is `v9.5.0`. I tried to change port by adding `next dev -p 4000` but still it has the same problem, I tried the following command that is in the documentations but still the same problem:

`npx create-next-app@latest nextjs-blog --use-npm --example`

[**GitHub discussions**](https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter)

And I even used yarn instead of NPM, and deleted the node_packages and then installing the dependencies once more, but still no luck.

Comment: what's the error message? there must be some. Does the console closes when it stops?

Comment: @itachi that is the thing, there is no error and after stopping the terminal it just wait for new commands.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue via these steps:

- delete your node_modules folder
- reinstall your packages using `npm i --force`

Answer (score 1):

Got it fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Windows 11 with node 18.16.1

What i do:

1. Re-installing nodejs
2. Then run again `npm run dev`
3. App is run but get this error `warn Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-gnu, but it was not installed`
4. Google it than find this [SWC Failed to Load](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc)
5. As that from article, do `npm i --force`

And now app runs as it should.