# NextJS 13.4 server stops when requesting a page

Tags: next.js13

When I start my NextJS 13 App Router app with `npm run dev`, it loads its environment variables, and when I request the certain page, it says

`- wait compiling /page (client and server)...`

and instantly, server stops.

Example page that I am requesting:

```
export default function Hello() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Hello from the page</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

I tried [this solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75825215/next-js-server-stops-a-few-seconds-after-running-npm-run-dev), however they do not solve the problem.

I uninstalled and reinstalled node.js, deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled, deleted `.next` folder and runned again, however it does not solve my problem either.

My NextJS version: 13.4.19